# Mongoose storing the same date and time in the object of array

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

My mongoose Schema as belows:

```
     clothes: [{
      _id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Clothes'
      },
      dateAdded: {
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now
     }
  }],
```

Now, If I'm pushing any new object into the clothes array within 1 min then it's storing the same date and time.

```
"clothes" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e3bcc9434a40d46e7eb2b25"),
        "dateAdded" : ISODate("2021-01-05T10:50:19.979Z")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c0599f6975b274a7654702a"),
        "dateAdded" : ISODate("2021-01-05T10:50:19.979Z")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d8cce493eb29c6e5af6be07"),
        "dateAdded" : ISODate("2021-01-05T10:50:19.979Z")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5db8344a1689662efbc6d816"),
        "dateAdded" : ISODate("2021-01-05T11:02:47.352Z")
    }
]
```

I really appreciates if you could help me out in this.

Comment: What do you want? Do you want it to store different dates? In each entry you do?

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this strange behavior.

This is because, you have defined the default value for `dateAdded` field as `Date.now`.

Remove the default value and push the `new Date()` value to the array whenever you are creating an entry.

This should fix the issue.

Comment: Hey there, I really appreciate for your quick reply but I want to do it automatically not manually.

Comment: @NaimishKher I tried your shema, it worked for me. Can you please share the query that you use to add entries to the array?